# AWS data pipeline job failing but there is no error message or error code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I tried running a data pipeline job but the EmrActivity step reached a FAILED status but there is no error code or error message:

Name:
@EMR cluster to perform the work_2013-09-03T16:15:00
View instance fields
Description:
Latest attempt count: 3, Tries left: 0
Select attempt for this instance:

Status:
FAILED
Error code:
Error message:

any idea why? Where can I find out more info about the underlying problem?

The job is simple: fire up EMR cluster and run a pig script (where xxx is my bucket name):

```
    {
    "objects": [
    {
    "id":"Default",
    "failureAndRerunMode":"cascade" 
    },
    {
    "id" : "MyScheduleID",
    "type" : "Schedule",
    "period" : "1 hour",
    "startDateTime" : "2013-09-03T19:00:00",
    "endDateTime" : "2013-09-03T20:00:00"
    },
    {
    "id" : "MyEmrCluster",
    "name" : "EMR cluster to perform the work",
    "type" : "EmrCluster",
    "hadoopVersion" : "0.20",
    "masterInstanceType" : "m1.small",
    "coreInstanceType" : "m1.medium",
    "coreInstanceCount" : "2",
    "terminateAfter": "1 Hours",
    "schedule": {
    "ref": "MyScheduleID"
    },
    "logUri":"s3://xxx/amazonlogs",
    "emrLogUri":"s3://xxx/amazonlogs"
    },

    {
    "id" : "MyEmrActivity",
    "name" : "Work to perform on my data",
    "type" : "EmrActivity",
    "runsOn" : {"ref" : "MyEmrCluster"},
    "schedule": {
    "ref": "MyScheduleID"
    },
    "step": "s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/pig/pig-script,--base-path,s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/pig/,--install-pig,--pig-versions,latest",
    "step": "s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/pig/pig-script,--base-path,s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/pig/,--pig-versions,latest,--run-pig-script,--args,-f,s3://xxx/carls_minimal_script.pig"
    }

    ]
    }
```

Does this config look OK?
I don't see anything in s3://xxx/amazonlogs

Answer (score 2):

Here are couple of things you could try

1. Go to "https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/home", find the corresponding cluster that got started (based on timestamp), click on "Debug", you should find logs about each step.
2. Or start an EMR cluster from AWS Console, login into the Master node, run the Pig script to check if its working.